# Create new table in HIVE selecting records based on unique condition

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I need to create data table in HIVE that will include IDs with 2 or more records that have 100 or more days, how do I do this in HIVE ?
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to count the number of rows with days at or above 100:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when days >= 100 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as cnt_100pl
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_100pl >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function as proposed by Gordon in his response. You can also do this using co-related sub-query as below. (Assuming the table name as my_table)

```
Select t1.*
from my_table t1 
where 2 <= (Select count(1) from my_table t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.days >= 100);
```

So the full query would be

```
Create table my_target_table
As
Select t1.*
    from my_table t1 
    where 2 <= (Select count(1) from my_table t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.days >= 100);
```